# Should we increase participation on meta?

Tags: discussion, promotion, meta

In a discussion about community vs. moderator decisions, [MikeSchinkel made a valid point](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129/question-about-hacking-core/133#133): *"We don't currently have enough people here to get a valid consensus; mostly it's the 3 moderators and you and @hakre."* I'm not completely sure, because (I believe) there is no way to see a user activity ranking on meta, but I guess he is right: user participation on meta is low.

Is this a problem? Should we try to increase participation on meta? Or should we accept that not everybody likes to think about meta stuff, and rather just asks or answers questions? If we want to increase participation, how should we do this? [Be more specific?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

To make it more personal (and elicit responses): Why are you here? Do you read but never reply to items on meta? Why? What could we do to make you want to spend time on meta too?

Answer (score 2):

I read everything on here usually, I often don't reply because 9/10 times Mike has created a short essay which I would only have created a short duplication of, to which I feel simply upvoting is best.

Comment: Now I feel bad... :-(

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Haha, I wouldn't. I've not been as active recently due to illness and exams, I only really find time to hang out in chat.

Answer (score 2):

Few meta discussions indicate IMHO that the main site just works. Nothing to worry.